# duplicate of what?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

I was reading here at meta and came across https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2524/closing-questions which is closed as a duplicate. Ok, What question is it a duplicate of?

In a more general case shouldn't the duplicate warning always have a link to the other question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question that it is a duplicate of has been deleted and you don't have enough reputation to view deleted posts.

In cases like this flag the closed question for moderator attention and explain the problem.

If you have enough reputation you could also vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what happened. Now How do we prevent this from happening?

Comment: @hildred: There is no way to guarantee such situations won't ever happen in a community-moderated site like stackexchange. If you see something out of the ordinary, your best option is to flag the question for moderator attention or take corrective action if you have enough reputation for it.